# How to use multiple condition in if statement in bash?

Tags: bash, if-statement, conditional-statements

Actually I am a new `bash` learner. I can use one condition in `bash` command. But how to use multiple condition in `bash`? I can use `if statement` like this:

```
read a
if [ $a = "y" ] ; then
   echo "YES"
elif [ $a = "Y" ] ; then
   echo "YES"
else
   echo "NO"
fi
```

I am finding something like this:

```
read a b c

if [ $a -eq $b and $b -eq $c ] ; then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ $a -eq $b or $b -eq $c ] ; then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

I just want to know, what to use instead of `and` and `or`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&&` for `and` (`||` for `or`)

```
read a b c

if [ "$a" == "$b" ] && [ "$b" == "$c" ] ; then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ "$a" == "$b" ] || [ "$b" == "$c" ] ; then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Comment: It is not working and showing the following errors in the error log:  
(1) solution.sh: line 3: [: 2: binary operator expected  
(2) solution.sh: line 5: [: 2: binary operator expected  
(3) solution.sh: line 5: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Comment: it is still giving wrong answer. for input ``6 6 6`` it is giving ``ISOSCELES``. see [this](https://ideone.com/BVo8fv)

Comment: You have to input `6 6 6` in one line

Answer (score 1):

Use `&&` and `||` to have multiple conditions. Additionally, change the square brackets to parentheses. Additionally change the `-eq` to `==` since you're comparing numbers and not strings. This works:

```
#!/bin/bash

read a b c

if (( $a == $b )) && (( $b == $c )); then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif (( $a == $b )) || (( $b == $c )) ; then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```

Comment: Yes I fixed your compile errors but paid no attention to other errors. Using the == operator would work in this case and fix your additional bug. I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks. there is no need to change square brackets. it works fine with them.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the prior answers, the correct way to use compound expression in a single `[` or `test` (they are the same) clause is to use `-a` (for `and`) and `-o` (for `or`).

(e.g. testing if both `file1` and `file2` are readable):

```
if [ -r "$file1" -a -r "$file2 ]
then
    # do something with the files
fi
```

Using `test` itself:

```
if test -r "$file1" -a -r "$file2
then
    # do something with the files
fi
```

Comment: Though I am not working on files. but it works fine. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The portable way of doing this inside `test` brackets is to use `-a` and `-o`.  Beware however that `-eq` is a numeric comparison, so you need to make sure your variables are numeric before comparing them.  Something like this:

```
#! /bin/sh

read a b c
expr "$a" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' \& "$b" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' \& "$c" : '[0-9][0-9]*$' >/dev/null || exit

if [ $a -eq $b -a $b -eq $c ] ; then
    echo "EQUILATERAL"
elif [ $a -eq $b -o $b -eq $c ] ; then
    echo "ISOSCELES"
else
    echo "SCALENE"
fi
```